# How to add organization,mobileno,email from bulk user endpoint "https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/scim2/Bulk" in WSO2IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I used "`https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/scim2/Bulk`" to upload bulk users to WSO2IS. How to add organization,email and mobileno to following data set.

Here is my data object.

```
{
    "failOnErrors": 1,
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkRequest"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "path": "/Users",
            "bulkId": "qwerty1",
            "data": {
                "schemas": [
                    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
                    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
                ],
                "userName": "Alexwso26.com",
                "password": "12345678",
                "name": {
                    "givenName": "Alex26 ",
                    "familyName": "Silva26"
                },
                "emails": [
                    {
                        "type": "home",
                        "value": "Alex26@g.com",
                        "primary": true
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It is working fine. But email didn't update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your user creation payload, it updates the user's home email. If you Navigate to the `Management console -> Main menu -> Claims -> List -> "http://wso2.org/claims" -> Emails - Home Email-> Edit` and tick `Supported by Default`, and view that created user's profile. You can see that the given value has been updated.

Change the email attribute like the following payload. Then you can update the `Email` attribute of the user. Also, the following payload contains the attribute format for mobile number and organization.

```
{
    "failOnErrors": 1,
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:BulkRequest"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "method": "POST",
            "path": "/Users",
            "bulkId": "qwerty1",
            "data": {
                "schemas": [
                    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:User",
                    "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User"
                ],
                "userName": "Alexwso26.com",
                "password": "12345678",
                "name": {
                    "givenName": "Alex26 ",
                    "familyName": "Silva26"
                },
                "emails": [
                    {
                        "value": "Alex26@g.com",
                        "primary": true
                    }
                ],
                "phoneNumbers": [
                    {
                        "value": "0771234567",
                        "type": "mobile"
                    }
                ],
                "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User" : {
                    "organization": "abc"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Refer to the following documents when forming payload when creating or managing users/groups via SCIM endpoint.

1. https://anuradha-15.medium.com/how-to-add-scim-extended-attributes-in-wso2-identity-server-71621f62c5d3
2. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643